# Does Cook and Ruzzo's result also hold for logspace-uniform AC0?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

In Cook's [famous paper on $\mathsf{NC}$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995885800413?via%3Dihub), he cites the following result:

> PROPOSITION 4.7 (Cook and Ruzzo, 1983). $\mathsf{AC}^k$ consists of those
>   problems solvable by uniform unbounded fan-in circuit families in $O(\log^k n)$ depth and $n^{O(1)}$ size.

where $\mathsf{AC}^k$ here is defined for $k \ge 1$ as the class of problems solvable by an ATM in $O(\log n)$ space and $O(\log^k n)$ alternation depth. (Of course, the definition of $\mathsf{AC}^k$ usually goes the other way around, but given the equivalence it is all just a matter of presentation.)

Note the above is the logspace-uniform version of $\mathsf{AC}$. It was later acknowledged that for $\mathsf{AC}^0$ the more restrictive dlogtime-uniformity is preferable. There is also an [interesting result](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000098915884/pdf?md5=41f3974316b00b53a57209c413986193&pid=1-s2.0-S0022000098915884-main.pdf) regarding the (in)equality of dlogtime- and logspace-uniformity of $\mathsf{AC}^0$. We also know that dlogtime-uniform $\mathsf{AC}^0$ is characterizable as the class of problems solvable by ATMs in $O(\log n)$ *time* (instead of space above) and $O(1)$ alternation depth.

Given that dlogtime- and logspace-uniformity most likely does make a difference for $\mathsf{AC}^0$ I am interested **whether the Cook and Ruzzo result can be extended to the case of $k = 0$ and logspace-uniform $\mathsf{AC}^0$**.
Unfortunately, in Cook's paper, "Cook and Ruzzo, 1983" is only listed as "unpublished theorem," so I was unable to check whether the proof also works for $k=0$ (and whether Cook and Ruzzo had simply neglected it for some reason).

Comment: Wouldn't PARITY be a counterexample?

Comment: @sdcvvc Of course, the classic counterexample :)  Make it an answer? I wonder now where exactly $k > 0$ is needed in the proof...